# How do I use clientOptions validatingCss

Tags: ajax, validation, yii

I want to show loading icon during the ajax validation that is defined in $form->error(). What do I need to do?

From documentation:

> [validatingCssClass: string, the CSS class to be assigned to the container whose associated input is currently being validated via AJAX. Defaults to 'validating'.]

```
<style type="text/css">
.validating {

    background-color: #FF02FF;
}
</style>
```

```
   <?php /** @var TbActiveForm $form */
    $form = $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'prezentacija-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
        'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'well'),
            'clientOptions'=>array(
                'validateOnType'=>true,

            ),
    )); ?>

  .....

  <?php echo $form->error($model,'naziv', array('validateOnType'=>true)); ?>
```

Comment: where on the page do you want to show this icon?

Comment: @bool.dev - after this input field.

Comment: so did you try adding a loading gif image as the background image, for the validating css class?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS2, set a [`background-image`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background-image), you might want to position this image also with [`background-position`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background-position). A sample:

```css
/* I have a new styles.css file in project/css folder */
.validating {
    background-image: url(../images/loading.gif); /* my image is in project/images folder */
    background-position: right center; /* positioning has to be done correctly */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Be sure that the image is of proper size, or you can use CSS3's [`background-size`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-background-20020802/#background-size) property(check for browser compatibility first).

---

On the Yii front, you don't have to add anything to your form's `clientOptions`, since the default `validatingCssClass` is already `validating`:

```php
'clientOptions'=>array(
    'validateOnType'=>true,
    'validatingCssClass'=>'validating'
    // if the class is validating, it's already applied, so the line is redundant, use only if your validating class is different
),
```

If you are testing on localhost, obviously you won't notice the change happening, since there is no network delay, but to test it, and position properly you will need to see it, therefore you can introduce some delay in the validating action method, using [php's `usleep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php):

```
public function actionActionId() {
    $model=new Prezentacija;
    usleep(10000); // for me 10000 microseconds was enough delay
    $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
    // ... rest of your code ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did something like that but it doesn't work. Only diference is that I use echo CActiveForm::validate(array($model)) instead of performAjaxValidation.

Comment: i think problem is client side, can you show your entire form code?

Comment: did you also check if ajax call is returning data correctly? did you follow CActiveForm::validate(), with a Yii::app()->end() ? basically we have entered debugging territory now, so have to figure out where is the error

Comment: I will answer you later today. Thank you :)

Comment: Yes, i tried with delay, but nothing happened. Here is my code (view, controller and json from fiddler) http://pastebin.com/FnhdqRsQ

Comment: did you notice changes when you try with background-color instead of image? see that the background image url is correct, image is found or not? other than that, everything looks fine in the code. try with background color once, and check if validating css is working, and get back to me